# Time difference between two values

Tags: r

```
data.frame(gid = c(1,1,1,2), gtime = c("2015-10-22 13:23:02", "2015-10-22 13:23:02", "2015-10-22 13:23:02", "2016-11-23 13:23:02"), wid = c (3,4,5,2) wtime = c("2015-10-22 13:33:02", "2015-10-22 13:53:02", "2015-10-22 14:23:02", "2016-11-23 13:28:02"), type = c("google", "google", "amazon", "yahoo")
```

How is it possible to take the difference between timestamp pf gtime and wtime? Example of expected output:

```
data.frame(difference = c("10 minutes", "30 minutes", "60 minutes", "24 hours and 5 minutes"), gid = c(1,1,1,2), gtime = c("2015-10-22 13:23:02", "2015-10-22 13:23:02", "2015-10-22 13:23:02", "2016-11-23 13:23:02"), wid = c (3,4,5,2) wtime = c("2015-10-22 13:33:02", "2015-10-22 13:53:02", "2015-10-22 14:23:02", "2016-11-24 13:28:02"), type = c("google", "google", "amazon", "yahoo")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert to Datetime class and use `difftime` with `unit` specified as `min`

```
df1$difference <- with(df1, difftime(as.POSIXct(wtime), 
        as.POSIXct(gtime), unit = 'min'))
```

Wrap with `as.numeric` if we need to remove the attribute

Answer (score 1):

You can directly subtract the time after converting it to `as.POSIXct`

```
with(df, as.POSIXct(wtime) - as.POSIXct(gtime))
#Time differences in mins
#[1] 10 30 60  5
```

Also can use lubridate's `ymd_hms` instead of `as.POSIXct`.

```
library(lubridate)
with(df, ymd_hms(wtime) - ymd_hms(gtime))
```